# Website for comparing SQL performance

Tags: sql-server, sql, code-review, performance-analysis, optimization

Is there a website which allows you to paste a DDL for your DB and two SQL statements, which can then recommend one (optionally including context such as; "if >10,000 rows use Query#2; else Query#1")?

I'm thinking similar to [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) combined with an AI (heuristic based recommendations based on query plan data gathered by running SQLs over various auto-generated data sets) [CodeFight](http://code-fight.club/).

Comment: NB: As pointed out by the SQLFiddle guys, SQLFiddle already creates query plans which can be used to give some idea of performance.  However this question goes beyond that; i.e. where the system could tell you in plain English which option was better, and could also say if there are contexts in which one option is preferred to another. https://twitter.com/sqlfiddle/status/572774804278755329